# How to properly feed data to StreamBuilder initialData parameter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using a StreamBuilder widget to display some data. When the app is recently opened, I wanted to display some initial data from my json file and feed it into the initialData optional keyword parameter of StreamBuilder.

Here is how I feed it:

```
MyStorage m = new MyStorage(); // Using path_provider, I accessed the json file inside this class
int x;

@override
void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getData();
}

getData() async{
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = await m._getMap;
    x = int.parse(myMap["total"]);
}

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    ...

    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: mystream, // coming from my BLoC class
        initialData: x,
        builder: (context, snapshot){
            return new Text("${snapshot.data}");
        }
...
```

The problem is it that the Text widget inside my StreamBuilder is displaying "null".

I tried to rewrite my code to this:

```
MyStorage m = new MyStorage();

Future<int> getData() async{
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = await m._getMap;
    return int.parse(myMap["total"]);
}

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    ...

    child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: mystream, // coming from my BLoC class
        initialData: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
            return new Text("${snapshot.data}");
        }

...
```

but it displayed on my Text widget as "Instance of Future:int"

I have no problem with my stream parameter in the StreamBuilder. It displays the correct value that I'm expecting from the BLoC class.

The only problem I had is the feeding of initialData from my json file.

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any kind of help. Thanks

**[UPDATE]**

After a long hours of thinking a solution, I gave up using initialData parameter since after I added `int` to `StreamBuilder` like this `StreamBuilder<int>()` it prompted me that it will only take a value of integer. I couldn't fed it with a type of Future or Stream so I decided not to use it. What I did was I nested a FutureBuilder inside the StreamBuilder through ConnectionState.

Here is what my code now:

```
MyStorage m = new MyStorage();

Future<int> getData() async{
    Map<String, dynamic> myMap = await m._getMap;
    return int.parse(myMap["total"]);
}

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
    ...

    child: StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: mystream, // coming from my BLoC class
        //initialData: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot){
            swith(snapshot.connectionState){
                case ConnectionState.none:
                    return new FutureBuilder(
                        future: getData(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                            return new Text('${snapshot.data}');
                        }
                    );
                case ConnectionState.active:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return new FutureBuilder(
                        future: getData(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                            return new Text('${snapshot.data}');
                        }
                    );
                case ConnectionState.done:
                    if (snapshot.hasData){
                        return new Text('${snapshot.data}');
                    }
                    return new FutureBuilder(
                        future: getData(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot){
                            return new Text('${snapshot.data}');
                        }
                    );
            }
        }

...
```

I know that this solution is very inefficient but I couldn't think of a better solution as of now.

Answer (score 0):

initialData is supposed to be the data to show before your actual data is available.

place `0` as initialData.

StreamBuilder has an additional parameter `stream` which is responsible for fetching your stream data. here you can do `stream: getData().asStream,`

edit:

Also make sure to specify the type of data you are expecting in your StreamBuilder. `StreamBuilder<int>()`

Comment: yes I have already set my stream parameter to something else, it listens from  my BLoC class. I have no problem with my stream parameter. I can't set my initialData to 0 because I wanted to display the value (integer) from my json file. Everytime I add an integer to my BLoC class, my json file is also updated so that when the user leaves/close the app, and when the user open it again, it will display the updated value from the json file. I'm sorry I didn't show the stream parameter on my post. I'll edit it.

Comment: So what Is the stream listening for? The intent of initialData is to be sort of like a placeholder while waiting for the stream to emit data. so the data should just be there immediately. in your case you are trying to fetch data from an async function, (which is asynchronous, means it belongs in the bloc), In my opinion thins logic should be moved into the bloc and stream from this. Whenever you update these parameters just update this stream

Comment: my stream listens for an integer. Yes, I used an async function.